# Having trouble displaying the outdoor variable

Tags: javascript

The loop is suppose to give me stored the array in the object Map and show me outdoor as the most profitable department.

I want to run a loop iterating through the array, I am just having trouble accessing that data again in the map and getting the most profitable value highest(sales) by the department.

E.g Combine all outdoors sales, hardware and carpentry to give u the total and console.log the the "outdoor" which is the highest.

```js
    var salesData = [{
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 4500,
      day: 'Monday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 1500,
      day: 'Monday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 5500,
      day: 'Monday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 7500,
      day: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 2505,
      day: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 1540,
      day: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 1500,
      day: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 8507,
      day: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 8009,
      day: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 12000,
      day: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 18007,
      day: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 6109,
      day: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 7005,
      day: 'Friday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 12006,
      day: 'Friday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 16109,
      day: 'Friday'
    }];
    var departmentMap = {};
    var high = "";
    
    function mostProfitableDepartment(salesList) {
      for (var i = 0; i < salesList.length; i++) {
    
        var currentDep = salesList[i];
    
        if (departmentMap[currentDep] === undefined) {
          departmentMap[currentDep] = 0;
        }
        departmentMap[currentDep] = departmentMap[currentDep] + 1
      }
      console.log(departmentMap);
    }
    
    
    mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);
    
    for (var depHigh in departmentMap) {
      if (departmentMap[depHigh] > high) {
        high = departmentMap[depHigh]
      }
    }
    
    console.log(high);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var salesData = [
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
];

// Build a obj map and sum up the sales of each department
var sales = salesData.reduce((obj, a) => {
  obj[a.department] = (obj[a.department] || 0) + a.sales
  return obj
}, {})

// Figure out which department is the highest
var high = Object.keys(sales).reduce((a, b) => sales[a] > sales[b] ? a : b )

console.log(sales)
console.log(high, sales[high])
```

Comment: Not exactly, but I actually have to do it as instructed above. Which I cant get right. @Endless

Comment: Sry, misunderstood your question, updated the answer

Comment: I cant actually understand the code, can u clarify please, without using the reduce function. @Endless

Comment: @Duvall912 they do have documentation you know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: This is pretty much the same as @Jamiec solution except that i use es6 [fat arrow](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.html)

Comment: Sorry but Im still new to programming. I try to understand the basics first like displaying the outdour through using a for in method. @Endless

Comment: You have to watch out for `for .. in` loops since you also have to check hasOwnProperty then, which [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) dose for you... [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns a array with all it's objects Own properties. And when you got an array of keys from sales you can then use reduce to loop over the array and dos save you one global variable

Comment: I tried that but it just displays me an array displaying Objects,Objects,Objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `.reduce` calls as below.

```js
var salesData = [{
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 4500,
      day: 'Monday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 1500,
      day: 'Monday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 5500,
      day: 'Monday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 7500,
      day: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 2505,
      day: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 1540,
      day: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 1500,
      day: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 8507,
      day: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 8009,
      day: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 12000,
      day: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 18007,
      day: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 6109,
      day: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      department: 'hardware',
      sales: 7005,
      day: 'Friday'
    }, {
      department: 'outdoor',
      sales: 12006,
      day: 'Friday'
    }, {
      department: 'carpentry',
      sales: 16109,
      day: 'Friday'
    }];

var aggregated = salesData.reduce(function(p,c){
   if(p[c.department] == undefined)
     p[c.department] = 0;
   p[c.department]+= c.sales;
   return p;
 },{});

console.log("total sales",aggregated);

var highest = Object.keys(aggregated).reduce(function(p,c){
  if(aggregated[c]>p.value)
    return {key:c,value:aggregated[c]}
  return p;
},{key:'notset',value:0});

console.log("best department", highest);
```

Comment: the code should be as structured as mine above mentioned just correct where it does not want to go through.I dont want to copy your code just need clarification on it to run the code by using the for in loop and object map.  @Jamiec

Comment: @Duvall912 your code is badly structured (global variables being modified by functions, bad practice). Take the time to understand a better way to accomplish your end goal.